# Attempting to add UNIQUE constraint, but told one already exists

Tags: python, database, postgresql, psycopg2

I have a large database with hundreds of tables. Each table has a functionally equivalent structure: one column is a unique identifier and the other a group membership indicator; that is, each row in the table has a unique identifier, but any number of rows can have the same group membership indicator. The tables are also created in pairs in the same schema, so the naming scheme for this database is `project_abbreviation.<name>_<suffix>`; for example, the pair `proj_abc.original_a` and `proj_abc.original_b`.

I inherited this database, and when the original developers constructed it, they did not add `UNIQUE` constraints to the unique identifier columns when the tables were created. As a result, whenever someone wants to change the group membership indicator for a row or set of rows in a given table, I have to add a `UNIQUE` constraint on the column if the table hasn't been modified since its creation. I do that programmatically:

```py
@connect
def make_column_unique(self, cursor, connection, column, suffix):
    sql = f"ALTER TABLE {self._schema}.{self._table}_{suffix} "
    sql += f"ADD CONSTRAINT unique_{column} UNIQUE ({column});"

    cursor.execute(sql)
    connection.commit()
```

where `@connect` is a decorator function which connects to the db instance, and the `cursor` and `connection` parameters are psycopg2 `Cursor` and `Connection` objects, respectively. I then call this in a try/except block:

```py
...

for suffix in ["a", "b"]:
    try:
        self.modify_table(...)
    except (Exception, psycopg2.DatabaseError) as e:
        self.make_column_unique("uid", suffix)
        self.modify_table(...)
...
```

Here is the function signature for `self.modify_table`:

```py
@connect
def modify_table(self, cursor, connection, data, suffix):
    sql = f"INSERT INTO {self._schema}.{self._table}_{suffix} (uid, group) "
    sql += "VALUES "

    zipped = list(zip(list(data["uid"]), list(data["group"])))
    row = 0

    for uid, group in zipped:
        row += 1
        sql += f"({uid},'{group}')" + ("," if row < len(zipped) else " ")

    sql += f"ON CONFLICT (uid) DO UPDATE "
    sql += "SET group = EXCLUDED.group;"

    cursor.execute(sql)
    connection.commit()
```

This approach worked exceedingly well and modified table entries properly, and set the `UNIQUE` constraint when one needed to be set.

Now, when I attempt to modify a table which has yet to be modified, I get a `There is no unique or exclusion constraint matching the ON CONFLICT specification` error, which kicks off the call to `make_column_unique`. However, when the program attempts to make the provided column unique, I get back a `relation "unique_<column>" already exists` error. Furthermore, **this only happens for tables of suffix `a`, *not* suffix `b`.** I went into pgAdmin4 to verify, and the desired modification occurred on the table with suffix `b`, but before and after the database transaction, the table with suffix `a` had no constraints applied to it:

**pgAdmin database viewer with no constraints**

[image: pgAdmin database viewer with no constraints]

Why am I getting these contradictory errors for only one type of table? It makes no sense to me to be told that a `UNIQUE` constraint doesn't exist, and then when I alter the table to include the constraint, to be told that it already exists.

Comment: Well without seeing what `modify_table()` is doing or example schema for unmodified `*._a and *.b` this is going to be hard to diagnose.

Comment: @AdrianKlaver added the code for `modify_table`.

Comment: Do you always open a new connection in `@connect` ? According to your error `relation "unique_<column>" already exists`, I assume the `CONSTRAINT` is added for the current transaction but not commited as expected (probably due to errors).

Comment: @MauriceMeyer yep, `@connect` always opens a new connection. The way I've structured the program, connections to the db are only created when a function which modifies something in the db is called, and those calls are never nested. I'll try forcibly closing the connection to see if that helps.

Comment: @MauriceMeyer **update: it does not help.** The same error crops up.

Answer (score 1):

## This is the dumbest possible answer I could give to this question.

It turns out that, in my predecessor's infinite wisdom, they decided to randomly sprinkle *duplicate values into columns that were supposed to be unique.* Easily fixed.